# /tmp/ directory not found in cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load a csv file from cloud storage, change the headers and reupload it to cloud storage.

```
// Import the Google Cloud client libraries
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const lineReplace = require('line-replace');

const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'bucket';
const srcFilename = 'bq/cost.csv';
const localFilename = 'tmp/cost.csv';
const bucketFilename = 'ga/cost.csv';

exports.properGAHeaders = async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const file = data;

    // Downloads the file
    if (file.name = srcFilename) {
      const options = {
        // The path to which the file should be downloaded, e.g. "./file.txt"
        destination: localFilename,
      };
      await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(srcFilename).download(options);

      await lineReplace({
        file: localFilename,
        line: 1,
        text: 'ga:date,ga:medium,ga:source,ga:adClicks,ga:adCost,ga:impressions,ga:referralPath,ga:adContent,ga:campaign,ga:adFinalUrl',
        addNewLine: false,
        callback: ({
          file, line, text, replacedText, error,
        }) => {
          if (error) { console.log(error); }
          console.log(`${replacedText} is replaced with ${text}!`);
        },
      });
      await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(localFilename, {
        destination: bucketFilename,
        // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
        gzip: false,
        // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
        // object you are uploading to a bucket.
        metadata: {
          // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
          // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
          // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
          cacheControl: 'no-cache',
        },
      });

      console.log(`${localFilename} uploaded to ${bucketName}`);
    }
  } catch (err) { console.error(err); }
};
```

When doing this I get the error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'tmp/cost.csv'`.

What could be the issue? 
I am running the functions with await so they should be running synchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full paths to tmp should start with a slash. For example: /tmp/cost.csv

Even better, use [os.tmpdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir) to build the path instead of hard coding a value that could theoretically change.

Comment: I receive an error when trying to use os.tmpdir(), os is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:25:17). I tried requiring os and then I get the message that it's called 2 times.

Comment: The issue was the missing / at the beginning.

Comment: That's weird, I am currently trying to list files in /tmp after writing out a file (using mmpjeg) and.. dir seems empty. I am now trying to use `os.TempDir()` in go..